# Matlab parfor on Windows stalls CPU

Tags: windows, matlab, parfor

I am facing a strange problem. I wrote a piece of code in Matlab which uses `parfor`. For testing, I ran the code on a 4 core Linux-machine. Once I was satisfied that it was working fine, I tried to run the same code on a Windows machine which has higher number of cores.

To my dismay, the `parfor` loop just gets stuck and runs even slower than the serial code. Its so slow, that the Windows-Task-Manager shows 0% usage on all 28 cores while the code is still running. The Matlab session doesn't generate any error but runs at a snails pace.

Similar (but not same) problems were recently reported on the Mathworks website [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/273509-parfor-loop-just-hangs-cpu-usage-goes-to-zero) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/245869-parfor-consistently-stalls-with-0-cpu-usage). Unlike the issue mentioned on Mathworks website, my code uses only Matlab commands and libraries.

Both machines (linux as well as Windows) have Matlab-2018a 64 bit installed.

Comment: What if you use a smaller number of cores on the Windows machine? E.g.  four cores as you tested it with on the Linux machine.

Comment: @NickyMattsson Yes, I tried that as well. Same results

Comment: Are you using symbolic math toolbox?

Comment: @SardarUsama No

Comment: Please provide [a sample of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that does this so your problem could be reproduced